# Advanced video chess lectures

Tags: chess-videos, recommendations

Could you recommend any video lessons online? I know STL Chess Club on YouTube and I am looking for something similar for 2000+ FIDE players.

Comment: Are you looking for free resources only, or are you also looking for paid services?

Comment: channels that review otb games are good. Kostya kavutsky and kasa korley's channel's are one examples...

Answer (score 2):

Chessable offers advanced courses (free and paid). Many of those courses have videos.

https://www.chessable.com/courses/for-advanced-players/

Comment: Videos are paid and cost a LOT. But many of the courses have very high quality.

Answer (score 0):

chess24.com has some [great video series](https://chess24.com/en/learn/videoseries?lang=en), but it's hard to make meaningful suggestions if you don't give us more specific details

Comment: This looks like a comment, rather than an answer...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16951)

Comment: @lodebari don't judge a book by its cover

Comment: @lodebari This does indeed provide an answer (chess24's courses can be useful to 2000+ rated players)

Comment: What makes this answer look like a comment to me is the absence of a link and the text "it's hard to make meaningful suggestions if you don't give us more specific details". I have added a link for you. I think the answer would improve by deleting the last part and adding a description of what can be found there, i.e., videos in several languages by great players, mostly paying, etc.